# How can I dispatch something with React / Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here's what I have so far:

```
export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    search: state.search
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    onSearch: (location) => (q) => dispatch(actions.push(getUrlWithQS(location, { qs: { q } }))),
    onClipCardClick: (location) => (clip) => dispatch(actions.push(getUrlWithQS(location, { pathname: `/clips/${clip.id}` })))
  }),
  (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => ({
    ...stateProps,
    ...dispatchProps,
    ...ownProps,
    onSearch: dispatchProps.onSearch(ownProps.location),
    onClipCardClick: dispatchProps.onClipCardClick(ownProps.location)
  })
)(Home)
```

I didn't write this (I inherited) it, so the `onSearch` apparently dispatches something and passes a new query? So what happens is the URL changes to http://localhost:5000/?q=whatever

How can I dispatch without changing the URL?

**EDIT**

```
import { push, goBack } from 'react-router-redux'
actions.push = push
```

And the component that triggers the `onSearch` looks like:

```
  onChange (e) {
    if(this.state.isMobile) {
      return this.props.onSubmit(e.target.value)
    }

    if(this.props.autoSearch) {
      this.props.onSubmit(e.target.value)
    }

    this.props.onAutocomplete(e.target.value)
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value,
      selectedSearch: false
    })

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the onSearch is invoked from an onSubmit handler of a form. It is the form submission (which is not automatically prevented by react) that causes the URL to change, and not the dispatch.

You can use:

```
event.stopPropagation()
event.preventDefault()
```

in the form onSubmit handler, so the submission is not handled by browser.

Comment: It is not on a form submit. It's on a change event of an input box.

Comment: Is the input box not inside a form that eventually gets submitted ?

Comment: Can you provide the definition of `actions.push` ?